# In R, how to add manually interaction between categorical variables using only the additive formula?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, interaction, cox-regression, r-forestplot

I want to fit a Cox regression model and plot the model coefficients using the forest plot via the SurvMiner::ggforest(). Unfortunately, the plot does not support interactions. They are skipped. Authors provide a temporary solution, but only for two numerical variables. They make the interaction term by multiplying the numbers and then they add this term to the model in the additive way.

So, rather than typing Y ~ X1 * X2, they type Y ~ X1 + X2 + X1_X2. Now, this additive term is estimated and can be plotted.

OK, now I have 3 categorical variables. How add the interaction terms manually in this manner?

The data:

```
data <- structure(list(time = c(3, 19, 13, 45, 87, 90, 24, 75, 17, 4, 
109, 16, 14, 45, 27, 48, 9, 40, 28, 16, 8, 32, 21, 15, 12, 15, 
8, 6, 35, 43, 63, 97, 22, 34, 16, 23, 70, 9, 28, 60, 105, 24, 
32, 41, 89, 38, 24, 82, 17, 79, 62, 17, 14, 68, 66, 5, 53, 30, 
14, 66, 59, 34, 53, 17, 15, 39, 20, 14, 10, 43, 11, 12, 47, 105, 
34, 111, 84, 39, 25, 17, 44, 19, 17, 113, 31, 26, 9, 81, 9, 77, 
38, 19, 84, 22, 86, 18, 56, 113, 13, 45), status = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), Branch = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("X", "Y"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the result:

```
> summary(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch*Gender, data = data))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch * Gender, 
    data = data)

  n= 100, number of events= 74 

                             coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
TypeB                     1.96981   7.16933  0.77083  2.555   0.0106 *
BranchY                   0.64430   1.90466  0.60113  1.072   0.2838  
GenderMale                0.66762   1.94960  0.59199  1.128   0.2594  
TypeB:BranchY             0.25488   1.29030  0.98364  0.259   0.7955  
TypeB:GenderMale         -0.87810   0.41557  0.88206 -0.996   0.3195  
BranchY:GenderMale        0.07818   1.08132  0.73736  0.106   0.9156  
TypeB:BranchY:GenderMale -0.66212   0.51576  1.13590 -0.583   0.5600
```

Now I want to replace the interaction with manually added terms. It cannot be `(A+B+C)^3` or `...A:B + A:C + B:C`, because the plot doesn't recognize this.

I need to create additional columns with the interactions.

How to do that? I managed in a tricky way, but it works only for the simplest part.

I simplified it to 2 factors: Type x Branch

That's what I expect to get:

```
> summary(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch, data = data))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch, data = data)

  n= 100, number of events= 74 

                 coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
TypeB          1.3439    3.8341   0.3834  3.506 0.000456 ***
BranchY        0.5761    1.7791   0.3430  1.680 0.093022 .  
TypeB:BranchY -0.2145    0.8070   0.4838 -0.443 0.657529
```

and I can replicate it:

```
> m <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch, data=data))
> summary(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Type + Branch + m$`TypeB:BranchY`, data = data))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Type + Branch + m$`TypeB:BranchY`, 
    data = data)

  n= 100, number of events= 74 

                     coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
TypeB              1.3439    3.8341   0.3834  3.506 0.000456 ***
BranchY            0.5761    1.7791   0.3430  1.680 0.093022 .  
m$`TypeB:BranchY` -0.2145    0.8070   0.4838 -0.443 0.657529
```

And now the forest plot **finds it**, but does not handle it properly.

[image]

And when I add the 3-level interaction, even the model fit is wrong:

What I expect to see:

```
> summary(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch * Gender, data = data))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch * Gender, 
    data = data)

  n= 100, number of events= 74 

                             coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
TypeB                     1.96981   7.16933  0.77083  2.555   0.0106 *
BranchY                   0.64430   1.90466  0.60113  1.072   0.2838  
GenderMale                0.66762   1.94960  0.59199  1.128   0.2594  
TypeB:BranchY             0.25488   1.29030  0.98364  0.259   0.7955  
TypeB:GenderMale         -0.87810   0.41557  0.88206 -0.996   0.3195  
BranchY:GenderMale        0.07818   1.08132  0.73736  0.106   0.9156  
TypeB:BranchY:GenderMale -0.66212   0.51576  1.13590 -0.583   0.5600  
---
```

What I see:

```
> m <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch * Gender, data=data))
> summary(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Type + Branch + m$`TypeB:BranchY` + 
+                 m$`TypeB:GenderMale` + 
+                 m$`BranchY:GenderMale` + 
+                 m$`TypeB:BranchY:GenderMale`, data = data))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Type + Branch + m$`TypeB:BranchY` + 
    m$`TypeB:GenderMale` + m$`BranchY:GenderMale` + m$`TypeB:BranchY:GenderMale`, 
    data = data)

  n= 100, number of events= 74 

                                coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
TypeB                         1.5403    4.6659   0.6437  2.393   0.0167 *
BranchY                       0.2168    1.2420   0.4274  0.507   0.6120  
m$`TypeB:BranchY`             0.6797    1.9732   0.8889  0.765   0.4445  
m$`TypeB:GenderMale`         -0.2101    0.8105   0.6536 -0.321   0.7479  
m$`BranchY:GenderMale`        0.7439    2.1042   0.4416  1.685   0.0921 .
m$`TypeB:BranchY:GenderMale` -1.3253    0.2657   0.9715 -1.364   0.1725
```

Is there any smart way to generate the interaction terms manually to add them to the forest plot? I think I'm close, but not sure *how* close...

Answer (score 0):

maybe using the `gtsummary` package will help here

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)

#plotting betas

data %>%
  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch*Gender, data = .) %>% 
  tbl_regression() %>%
  plot()
```

[image: beta plot]

```
#plotting hazard ratios
    data %>%
      coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Type * Branch*Gender, data = .) %>% 
      tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
      plot()
```

[image: hr plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposal. If my problem won't be solved, I will use this awesome solution, if anything else fails, with some additional work to display the CIs and p-values + the output of the Cox model, as the ggforest() does. The ggforest would give me the informations I need out of the box. I'll definitely note this one. Thank you again!

Comment: no problem. If you need full customization you might want to look into the `broom` package which can convert model objects into data.frames. from there you can manipulate the model coefficients more easily and use ggplot2 to customize your plot

Comment: I found also this one: GGally::ggcoef_model(fit1, exponentiate = TRUE)
This produces an awesome plot along with p-v. More examples:
https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggcoef_model.html

Comment: I'm wondering if you guys are able to explain the meaning of the coefficients? There just might be a reason why this sort of plot was not applied to interactions.

Comment: I agree with you that the coefficients here are difficult to interpret and this function was originally intended to be used with univariate models. I realized that it can accommodate multivariable models and  decided to show how to use the function/ some statisticians do still find these plots useful in the multivariable setting.

Comment: I find them useful for simple multivariable models, but not for interaction models. Many people attempt to interpret coefficients of the interaction terms in the same manner as they do variables that are not involved in interactions. They generally fail when they do so.